# backward slash to forward slash using javascript

Tags: javascript, string, replace

I want to replace "\" with "/" in a javascript string.

```
var p = "D:\upload\date\csv\sample.csv";
```

to:

```
var p = "D:/upload/date/csv/sample.csv";
```

But I am getting error in first line itself. "SyntaxError: malformed Unicode character escape sequence".

How to do this ? Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one should be `var p = "D:\\upload\\date\\csv\\sample.csv";`

A single `\` is for escaping (or other stuff). In your case the `\upload` is a problem because `\u` would indicate an unicode character.

To replace, use: `p = p.replace(/\\/g, '/');`

Answer (score 0):

```
var p = 'D:\\upload\\date\\csv\\sample.csv';
p = p.replace(/\\/g, '/');
```

Answer (score 0):

also

```
p=p.split("\\").join("/");
```